# Use of Criminal Rating in San Andreas?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I have a `Pee-Wee` rating right now. Can I do anything with that or it's just for fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Criminal Rating is a rating level in all games in the GTA III Era based on the criminal activities of the player. In Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas, the criminal rating can be viewed in the Stats section in the pause menu. A new game starts the criminal rating at 0. GTA San Andreas did not feature the Media Attention statistic like Vice City did.

--Wiki located [here](http://gta.wikia.com/Criminal_Ratings_in_GTA_San_Andreas)

It basically is just a "How evil are you" and provides no positive or negative effect. Just the satisfaction that running over multiple people at a time gets you that much closer to being the Godfather. [Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/561641-grand-theft-auto-vice-city/faqs/23278)